# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Oblig1.Models.User' because it does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Keep getting this error and cant seem to find where i am going wrong, anybody who can lend a hand?

This is my View, Minside.cshtml:

```
@model Oblig1.Models.User
<br />
<br />
<br />

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kontoinformasjon</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Ordrehistorikk</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <br />
        <br />
        <table class="table">
            @foreach (var user in Model)
            {
                @user.Firstname
            }
        </table>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Ordrehistorikk</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Minside()
    {
        var db = new PastaContext();

        string compareEmail = (string)Session["User"];
        User foundUser = db.Users.Find(compareEmail);
        if(foundUser == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(foundUser);
        }           
    }
```

I have tried to change the first line in the view to @model IENumberable aswell.

All i really want to happen is that i list out the information of 1 single user to the view.

Comment: Does `Oblig1.Models.User` implement `IEnumerable` interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state at the top of your file that the model for the MVC template is a User

```
@model Oblig1.Models.User
```

So you don't need the foreach, just type FirstName directly in your view.

```
@model.FirstName
```

Comment: wow you just made me cry, it worked. thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

you need IEnumerable Type Model, Like this for `foreach loop`

```
@model IEnumerable<Oblig1.Models.User>
```

And If you have single user object the you dont't need of foreach loop.
you can just write

`@model.FirstName`